# Cronómetro para aplicación de deporte

Tags: android-studio, countdowntimer

Estoy tratando de hacer un cronometro en Android studio para una aplicación de deportes pero al momento de que el cronometro inicia no se ve reflejado

Al momento de que inicia el cronometro quiero que se vea reflejado en el textview que tengo pero se queda en el mismo formato que es 00:00 no cambia. Al momento de apretar el boton va todo bien por que con un Toast Verifique y si dice finalizado, pero no entiendo por que no se me va cambiando el texto en el momento

```
public void IniciarCuenta(){
        int Minuto = (Integer.valueOf(Minutos.getText().toString()) * 60 * 1000);
        int Segundo = (Integer.valueOf(Segundos.getText().toString()) * 1000);
        long Valor = Minuto + Segundo;
        CountDownTimer TIEMPO = new CountDownTimer(Valor, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                long tiempo = 1/1000;
                int minuto = (int) (tiempo/ 60);
                long segundos = tiempo % 60;

                String Minutos_mostrar = String.format("%02d", minuto);
                String SegundoMostrar = String.format("%02d", segundos);



                Mostrar.setText(""+Minutos_mostrar+":"+ SegundoMostrar); //Aqui deveria ir cambiando el valor

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Finalizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Mostrar.setText("FINALIZO");

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que lo solucionarías, pero como sigue abierta la pregunta ...

Estaba buscando algo similar, y cogiendo tu código, lo modifiqué para encontrar más o menos lo que buscabas

```
//método para iniciar el contador decreciente
public void IniciarCuenta(){

    //Capturo de los segundos de tres TextView donde tengo las horas, los 
          //minutos y los segundos multiplicando los minutos por 60 y las 
          //horas por 60 y por 60 para convertirlos todos en segundos
    segundos = (Integer.parseInt(Minutos.getText().toString()) * 60) + ((Integer.parseInt(Horas.getText().toString()) * 60) * 60))

    //instanciamos el CountDownTimer, que es el contador que va hacia atrás 
    new CountDownTimer(segundos * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {

        //método que realiza los cálculos
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            segundos = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            //calculamos las horas, dividiendo los segundos entre 3600
            int horas = segundos / (60 * 60);
            //capturamos el resto que sobra del las horas
            int tempMint = (segundos - (horas * 60 * 60));
            //calculamos los minutos diviendo el resto entre 60
            int minutos = tempMint / 60;
            //calculamos el resto y lo llevamos a la variable segundos
            segundos = tempMint - (minutos * 60);

            //mostramos los resultados de los cálculos en el textView con la
                 //salida formateada en dos dígitos
            txtCronoT.setText(String.format("%02d", horas)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", minutos)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", segundos));
        }

        //Cuando finaliza el método
        public void onFinish() {
            //Escribimos el texto en el TextView
            txtCronoT.setText("Finalizado");
        }
    }.start();  //Iniciamos el método
}
```

Podríamos haber ahorrado el pasarlo todo a segundos y volver a pasarlo todo para los cálculos a horas, minutos y segundos, sólo está agregado para que se vea como se puede hacer si recibes el dato de forma individual o en única cifra.

teniendo los dos métodos, sería simplemente eliminando uno de los cálculos